# Convert to Laravel exception?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Currently in a package, it has `HttpException` exception

```
namespace DigitalOceanV2\Exception;

class HttpException extends \RuntimeException implements ExceptionInterface
{

}
```

Is there a way to to convert it Laravel `HttpResponseException` uses without touching that exception from the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch that exception and rethrow it.

In your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \DigitalOceanV2\Exception) {
        throw new HttpResponseException;
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Edit: I haven't tested this but according to [the exception class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Exceptions/HttpResponseException.php). You can pass a response as a parameter to the constructor. So you should be able to do this:

```
$response = response($exception->getMessage());
throw new HttpResponseException($response);
```

Comment: Will it pass the message to `HttpResponseException` ?

Comment: Yes, it will add the message automatically.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the Answer. Just wondering if there a way to return json response via HttpResponseException?

Comment: Instead of rethrowing the exception, you can simply return a response from the `render()` method. E.g. `if ($e instance of Exception) { return response(['json' => 'data']); }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is late, but at least on Laravel 8+ there is a `\App\Exceptions\Handler::report` method that I think would be more appropriate to override and put such logic - e.g. converting the exception to a different/custom class.

In fact `render` suggests *how* to render it, not what to do with it.

```php
public function report(Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \DigitalOceanV2\Exception) {
        throw new HttpResponseException;
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```